# Xbox Live Email Extension?

Tags: xbox-network, xbox

I have an Xbox Live account. When I made it, I don't recall selecting much more than my username.

Now I want to login with to a website but I need to know what the standard ending for an Xbox Live account is.

For example: MyUserName@**ThisIsThePartIWant**.com

It could be @hotmail.com or @msn.com or @xbox.com.  I just don't know (and I don't have my Xbox with me to go dig around and see if it is on there).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Xbox Live accounts are associated with a Windows Live ID](http://support.xbox.com/en-us/pages/xbox-live/how-to/xbox-live-account-management/manage-live-id.aspx) (formerly MSN Passport I believe).

If you had a Hotmail email account, a MSN/WL Messenger account, or a MSN Passport from some other MSN service prior to the registration of your Xbox Live Gamertag, you probably associated your Xbox Live account with that (now) Windows Live ID.

A quick search reveals that it is also possible for Windows Live IDs to expire from lack of use, even if that Windows Live ID is associated to an active Xbox Gamertag. Please see [Major Nelson's blog post](http://majornelson.com/archive/2009/02/19/windows-live-id-s-and-gamertags.aspx) for more details on that possibly related issue.

I recommend you A) try logging-in with any Windows Live IDs you may have used at the time you registered your Xbox Live gamertag, or B) use the Xbox with has your gamertag saved to it to [change your associated Windows Live ID](http://support.xbox.com/en-us/pages/xbox-live/how-to/xbox-live-account-management/manage-live-id.aspx#section-4).

Best of luck getting your account sorted out.

Comment: Windows Live ID is now called Microsoft Account.

Answer (score 1):

as jmlane said; all Windows Live accounts (aka Xbox Live accounts) are set up using a pre-existing email address.

Now, if you were wanting to be able to give out a address through which someone else could send an email and you'd receiving it as a Xbox Live message in your Xbox dashboard then that is something else. I am unaware of such a service although I don't know for sure that none exist.